# Is there a way i can make the image resize as the browser height changes?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way I can make these images on this webpage resize themselves to fit the height of the browser as the browser window shrinks?

I've already tried giving images `max-width:100%; height:auto;` but it doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

as you can see, the main slider on this webpage is set height:auto and the image shrinks as the screenresolution changes.

all I need to do is to get the image above resize itself to fit to the height.

thanks.

here is the site I've been working on: http://ike.co.kr/English/main.html

Comment: 4 images ?  have you tried 100vh/4 . `img{height:25vh; width:auto/* reset to auto if needed */}` .

Answer (score 1):

**METHOD 1:** you can use viewport height unit <sup>(*)</sup> `vh`, where `100vh` is roughly equals full window height

[**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8uqmqfqn/1/)

```css
body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.full-height{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<img class="full-height" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxUiR.png">
```

---

**METHOD 2:** Due to a bit lack of support -IE *as most of the time*- for viewport units you can use `height:100%` but the `html` and `body` have to have a `height:100%` too like:

[**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8uqmqfqn/2/)

```css
html, body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%; /* this is mandatory to get the full height for children */
}
.full-height{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<img class="full-height" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxUiR.png">
```

---

**METHOD 3:** if you don't like CSS, or for some reason it didn't work for you, with jQuery:

[**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8uqmqfqn/3/)

```js
var winH = $(window).height();
$('#full-height').css({'height': winH});
```

```css
body{ padding:0; margin:0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="full-height" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxUiR.png">
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(*)</sup> Resources:

- http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport-units
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Answer (score 0):

I inspect your code, just put below jQuery in script tag.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main_thumbnail img").css('height',($(window).height()/4))
}
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".main_thumbnail img").css('height',($(window).height()/4))
}
```

Hope this will helps you.